# How to change the background colour of a cell in a QCalendarWidget using an SQL database

Tags: python, sqlite, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

This is not duplicate question of [How to Output sql data onto a QCalendarWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645241/how-to-output-sql-data-onto-a-qcalendarwidget/60645501#60645501)

This is an addon of that question.

This also isn't a duplicate of [Highlight date interval in a Qt5 Calendar Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165586/highlight-date-interval-in-a-qt5-calendar-widget?noredirect=1&lq=1) as this is just highlighting cells when the user selects it on the actual QT page and not by using SQL data. It also isn't a duplicate question of [Coloring PyQt5 QCalendarWidget cell and printing data inside the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253427/coloring-pyqt5-qcalendarwidget-cell-and-printing-data-inside-the-cells?noredirect=1&lq=1) as the answer doesnt do what i want my program to do which is to change the background Colour of a particular cell of the calendar using my sql database to do this, as well as i couldnt get the answer to work.

In the first linked question i was asking how a user would press a date and it would output the text corresponding to that date if that date was in a sql database. With some help I managed to get this working. Now what i want to do is highlight those dates with a blue background like how the current date is highlighted by a red background.

My QT page i have made is this:

[My QT Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koCzM.png)

My Database is this:

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoHBB.png)

And my code is this:

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Calendar.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
import datetime
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QFont, QTextCharFormat, QTextLength,
        QTextTableFormat)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDateTimeEdit,
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QSpinBox, QTextBrowser, QVBoxLayout,
        QWidget)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1200, 900)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1200, 900))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.Header = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.Header.setEnabled(False)
        self.Header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 1300, 110))
        self.Header.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1300, 110))
        self.Header.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1300, 110))
        self.Header.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-width : 1.2px;\n"
"border-style:inset;")
        self.Header.setObjectName("Header")
        self.LECTURP = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LECTURP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(512, 2, 180, 61))
        self.LECTURP.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 176, 240);\n"
"font: 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"text-decoration: underline;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 28pt \"Calbri\";\n"
"text-decoration: underline;")
        self.LECTURP.setObjectName("LECTURP")
        self.LecturpBanner = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.LecturpBanner.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 60, 561, 31))
        self.LecturpBanner.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 176, 240);\n"
"font: 14pt \"Calibri\";")
        self.LecturpBanner.setObjectName("LecturpBanner")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 1141, 661))
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"selection-background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.DateInfoOutput = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.DateInfoOutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 778, 1141, 97))
        self.DateInfoOutput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 16pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"border-width : 1.2px;\n"
"border-style:inset;")
        self.DateInfoOutput.setText("")
        self.DateInfoOutput.setObjectName("DateInfoOutput")
        self.WeekNumber = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.WeekNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(56, 168, 113, 49))
        self.WeekNumber.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.WeekNumber.setObjectName("WeekNumber")
        self.calendarWidget.raise_()
        self.Header.raise_()
        self.LECTURP.raise_()
        self.LecturpBanner.raise_()
        self.DateInfoOutput.raise_()
        self.WeekNumber.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.editor = QTextBrowser()


        self.calendarWidget.clicked[QDate].connect(self.dateClicked)


    def dateClicked(self, clickedDate):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db") 
        crsr = connection.cursor() 
        crsr.execute(
            'SELECT Text FROM Calendar WHERE Day = ? AND Month = ? AND YEAR = ?', 
            (clickedDate.day(), clickedDate.month(), clickedDate.year()))
        result = crsr.fetchone()

        if result:
            self.DateInfoOutput.setText(result[0])
        else:
            self.DateInfoOutput.setText('')


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.LECTURP.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LECTURP"))
        self.LecturpBanner.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lecture, Exam, Coursework, Timetable, Uploader and Reminder Program."))
        self.WeekNumber.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Week No."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Ive tried to follow your comments and i have done this:

```
    crsr.execute('SELECT Date FROM Calendar2 WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
        Dates3 = crsr.fetchone()
        Dates3 = str(Dates3)
        Dates3 = Dates3.replace("'", "")
        Dates3 = Dates3.replace('(', '')
        Dates3 = Dates3.replace(')', '')
        Dates3 = Dates3.replace(',', '')
        print(All_Dates)

        print(Dates3)
        Dates3 = Dates3.replace('/', ',')


        self.dates = { QDate(2020, 3, 20): ["Um Sure"] }

        format = QTextCharFormat() 
        format.setBackground(QColor("salmon")) 
        self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(Dates3, format)
```

whever i try to run this i get this error:

> Message=setDateTextFormat(self, Union[QDate, datetime.date], QTextCharFormat): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

I've tried to use the self.dates variable but that also didn't work. I'm not sure how to convert the date into a format thats acceptable for the QDate part of the output.

Ok everything works but when i made this while loop i was just wondering if im doing wrong python or wrong QT.

```
    Count = 1 
        while Count <= list3:
            connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db") 
            # This is the code for the database cursor 


            Current_Day = datetime.date.today().strftime("%A,")
            Current_Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")
            Current_Month = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")


            Combined_Date = ("It is a " + Current_Day + " It is the " + Current_Date + " of " + Current_Month)

            Combined_Date = str(Combined_Date)

            self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)

            cursor = self.editor.textCursor()



            crsr.execute('SELECT Date FROM Calendar2 WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
            Dates3 = crsr.fetchone()
            Dates3 = str(Dates3)
            Dates3 = Dates3.replace("'", "")
            Dates3 = Dates3.replace('(', '')
            Dates3 = Dates3.replace(')', '')
            Dates3 = Dates3.replace(',', '')


            crsr.execute('SELECT Text FROM Calendar2 WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
            Text = crsr.fetchone()
            Text = str(Text)
            Text = Text.replace("'", "")
            Text = Text.replace('(', '')
            Text = Text.replace(')', '')
            Text = Text.replace(',', '')


            print(Dates3)

            Dates3 = Dates3.replace('/', ' ')
            Dates3 = Dates3.replace("'", '')
            Dates3.split()

            sqlDay = int(Dates3[0:2])
            sqlMonth = int(Dates3[3:4])
            sqlYear = int(Dates3[6:10])



            self.dates = { QDate(sqlYear, sqlMonth, sqlDay): ["Hi"]}



            format = QTextCharFormat() 
            format.setBackground(QColor("lightblue")) 


            Count = Count + 1
            for date, value in self.dates.items(): 
                self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(date, format)
                self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Text)
            else:
                self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)
        else:
            self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)
```

Comment: To do what you want you have 2 steps: 1) Obtain the dates using an SQL query and convert it to QDates that, according to the code you provide, you know how to do it. 2) Since you already have the QDates then you can change the background color of each QDate using setDateTextFormat as the duplicate shows.

Comment: It seems that you want us to provide the code to make a copy-paste and unfortunately SO is not that type of site. Instead of posting the same question you should use the information from the duplicate to show your intent. According to your argument if 2 users published: How to change the background color of the weekends? and How to change the font color of the weekdays? they are not the same and clearly they are the same.

Comment: Here it does not matter if you have spent a day or years trying to solve (there is a question for years that have not been answered) so this argument is irrelevant. I see the same code from your previous question without showing an effort to solve your current problem. Practically I already told you the procedure: to change the format of a certain date then you must build a QDate that has the information of the date, and then use: `format = QTextCharFormat()` `format.setBackground(QColor("salmon"))` `your_calendar.setDateTextFormat(date, format)`   where you set the format of that date.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand some questions never get answered but every question i asked you either reviewed it or closed it so i was really annoyed that you kept on closing them. Its just thaqt this has been for an important piece of work for my school and ive been stressing about it because its the main feature of my program but i couldn't get it to work. Im sorry for having an arrogant tone ive just been really worried that i woudnt get it done on time.

Comment: For the task we all have to create a program but using QT but were all amking different programs and im the only one trying to do this feature. Anyway ive tried using your code and im not sure what to do because. Ill edit the question because i cant put it all into a comment

Comment: change  `self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(Dates3, format)` to `for date, value in self.dates.items():` `self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(date, format)`. Your mistake is trivial and has nothing to do with PyQt but with basic python: how to iterate over a dictionary.

Comment: Ok this works for me. Thank you :). i've got another error when im trying to run through a database and highlight every date in a while loop. It prints out the text that is related to the date but not highlighting that date. I was just wondering if the while loop is overwriting each highlight so theres no highlight at all. Im going to update my question witht the added code.

Comment: what is the output for  `crsr.execute('SELECT Text FROM Calendar2 WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))`  `text, *_ = crsr.fetchone()` `print(type(text), text)`

Comment: I get     15/01/2020
    <class 'str'> Hydrology Coursework Hand-In
    28/01/2020
    <class 'str'> Hydrolodgy Exam
    14/02/2020
    <class 'str'> The Earth: Interior - Exam
    29/02/2020
    <class 'str'> The Earth: Coursework
    29/02/2020
    <class 'str'> Principles of Geology - Recap 'Quiz'
    10/03/2020
    <class 'str'> Birthday
    24/3/2020
    <class 'str'> Birthday
    18/04/2020
    <class 'str'> Volcanoes and the Mantle - Recap 'Quiz'
    16/05/2020
    <class 'str'> Fieldwork - Start
    8/07/2020
    <class 'str'> Fieldwork - End

Comment: which is what is in the database

Comment: share your database

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cua9gypkl869hnm/Calendardatabase.db?dl=0 At the moment i am using the Calendar 2 table but for the current day i am using the Calendar Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure for this case is:

- Make the query to the database.
- Get the date as a string.
- Convert the string to [`QDate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html) using the [`QDate.fromString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-2) method pointing to the appropriate format, and
- set the format for that date in the [`QCalendarWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html) using [`QCalendarWidget.setDateTextFormat()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcalendarwidget.html#setDateTextFormat).

```py
import os
import sqlite3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    calendar = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget()
    calendar.show()

    connection = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "Calendardatabase.db"))
    crsr = connection.cursor()
    crsr.execute("""SELECT Date FROM Calendar2""")

    date_format = "d/M/yyyy"
    cell_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    cell_format.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("red"))

    for row in crsr.fetchall():
        date_str, *_ = row
        dt = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date_str, date_format)
        if dt.isValid():
            calendar.setDateTextFormat(dt, cell_format)
        else:
            print("{} does not match format {}".format(date_str, date_format))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. It finally works I'll revise my post so that people can see my finished code so that if anyone wants follow it they can

Answer (score 0):

After getting help from @eyllanesc i have fully completed my program and i'm going to leave my program here so that if anyone gets stuck they can use my program as a guide or just help in any case.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Calendar.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3
import datetime
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QColor, QFont, QTextCharFormat, QTextLength,
        QTextTableFormat)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QComboBox, QDateTimeEdit,
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QSpinBox, QTextBrowser, QVBoxLayout,
        QWidget)

class Ui_CalendarWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, CalendarWidget):
        CalendarWidget.setObjectName("CalendarWidget")
        CalendarWidget.resize(1200, 900)
        CalendarWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        CalendarWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1200, 900))
        CalendarWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);")
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(CalendarWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.Header = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.Header.setEnabled(False)
        self.Header.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 1300, 110))
        self.Header.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1300, 110))
        self.Header.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1300, 110))
        self.Header.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-width : 1.2px;\n"
"border-style:inset;")
        self.Header.setObjectName("Header")
        self.LECTURP = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.LECTURP.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(512, 2, 180, 61))
        self.LECTURP.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 176, 240);\n"
"font: 8pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"text-decoration: underline;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 28pt \"Calbri\";\n"
"text-decoration: underline;")
        self.LECTURP.setObjectName("LECTURP")
        self.LecturpBanner = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.LecturpBanner.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 60, 561, 31))
        self.LecturpBanner.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"color: rgb(0, 176, 240);\n"
"font: 14pt \"Calibri\";")
        self.LecturpBanner.setObjectName("LecturpBanner")
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 1141, 661))
        self.calendarWidget.setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);\n"
"selection-background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.DateInfoOutput = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.DateInfoOutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 778, 1141, 97))
        self.DateInfoOutput.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 16pt \"Calibri\";\n"
"border-width : 1.2px;\n"
"border-style:inset;")
        self.DateInfoOutput.setText("")
        self.DateInfoOutput.setObjectName("DateInfoOutput")
        self.WeekNumber = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.WeekNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(56, 168, 113, 49))
        self.WeekNumber.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"font: 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.WeekNumber.setObjectName("WeekNumber")
        self.calendarWidget.raise_()
        self.Header.raise_()
        self.LECTURP.raise_()
        self.LecturpBanner.raise_()
        self.DateInfoOutput.raise_()
        self.WeekNumber.raise_()
        CalendarWidget.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(CalendarWidget)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        CalendarWidget.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(CalendarWidget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(CalendarWidget)

        self.editor = QTextBrowser()


        self.calendarWidget.clicked[QDate].connect(self.dateClicked)

        connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db")
        crsr = connection.cursor()

        Current_Day = datetime.date.today().strftime("%A,")
        Current_Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")
        Current_Month = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")

        Combined_Date = ("It is a " + Current_Day + " It is the " + Current_Date + " of " + Current_Month)

        Combined_Date = str(Combined_Date)

        self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)


        #This is where the SQL Data is converted to d/M/yyyy and is then highlighted onto the calendar widget itself.

        connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db")
        crsr = connection.cursor()
        crsr.execute("""SELECT Date FROM Calendar2""")

        date_format = "d/M/yyyy"
        cell_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        cell_format.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("lightblue"))

        for row in crsr.fetchall():
            date_str, *_ = row
            dt = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date_str, date_format)
            if dt.isValid():
                self.calendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(dt, cell_format)
            else:
                self.DateInfoOutput.setText("{} does not match format {}".format(date_str, date_format))









    def dateClicked(self, clickedDate):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db") 
        # This is the code for the database cursor 
        crsr = connection.cursor() 
        Count = 1
        crsr.execute('SELECT Day FROM Calendar WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
        RawDay = crsr.fetchone()
        Day = str(RawDay)
        Day = Day.replace('(', '')
        Day = Day.replace(')', '')
        Day = Day.replace(',', '')
        Day = int(Day)

        crsr.execute('SELECT Month FROM Calendar WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
        RawMonth = crsr.fetchone()
        Month = str(RawMonth)
        Month = Month.replace('(', '')
        Month = Month.replace(')', '')
        Month = Month.replace(',', '')
        Month = int(Month)

        crsr.execute('SELECT Year FROM Calendar WHERE Number = ?', (Count,))
        RawYear = crsr.fetchone()
        Year = str(RawDay)
        Year = Year.replace('(', '')
        Year = Year.replace(')', '')
        Year = Year.replace(',', '')
        Year = int(Year)        


        Current_Day = datetime.date.today().strftime("%A,")
        Current_Date = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d")
        Current_Month = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B")


        Combined_Date = ("It is a " + Current_Day + " It is the " + Current_Date + " of " + Current_Month)

        Combined_Date = str(Combined_Date)

        self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)

        cursor = self.editor.textCursor()

        All_Dates = (Day, Month, Year)

        self.selectedDate = QDate.currentDate()
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Calendardatabase.db") 
        crsr = connection.cursor() 
        crsr.execute(
            'SELECT Text FROM Calendar WHERE Day = ? AND Month = ? AND YEAR = ?', 
            (clickedDate.day(), clickedDate.month(), clickedDate.year()))
        result = crsr.fetchone()

        self.Date = (clickedDate.day() , '/' , clickedDate.month() , '/' , clickedDate.year())



        if result:
            self.DateInfoOutput.setText(result[0])


        else:
            self.DateInfoOutput.setText(Combined_Date)








    def retranslateUi(self, CalendarWidget):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        CalendarWidget.setWindowTitle(_translate("CalendarWidget", "CalendarWidget"))
        self.LECTURP.setText(_translate("CalendarWidget", "LECTURP"))
        self.LecturpBanner.setText(_translate("CalendarWidget", "Lecture, Exam, Coursework, Timetable, Uploader and Reminder Program."))
        self.WeekNumber.setText(_translate("CalendarWidget", "Week No."))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    CalendarWidget = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_CalendarWidget()
    ui.setupUi(CalendarWidget)
    CalendarWidget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To get this program to work you will also need my database and you can get that from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cua9gypkl869hnm/Calendardatabase.db?dl=0
If you just put this in the same folder as the program file this should work.

Thank you for all the help @eyllanesc i would've been stuck for weeks on this problem withhout your help :)